# Format MySQL using CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Thanks to some help  I have a MySQL query that starts on 2014-10-10 and fines the amount of holidays in 12 months period eg 2014-10-10 to 2015-10-09 then 2015-10-10 to 2016-10-09

```
SELECT 
    e.name AS Employee,
    CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.startdate)/365) as Year,
    count(h.date) as Holidays_Taken
FROM employees AS e
LEFT JOIN holidays_taken AS h ON e.id = h.empid
WHERE e.id = 1
GROUP BY Year
```

With a result

```
+----------+------+---------------+
| Employee | Year | Holidays_Taken|
+----------+------+---------------+
| Jon      | 1    | 5             |
+----------+------+---------------+
| Jon      | 2    | 1             |
+----------+------+---------------+
```

Is it possible to have the year show 2014-10-10 to 2015-10-09 instead of year 1 then 2015-10-10 to 2016-10-09 for year 2

Here's my [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/371a7/1)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding the dates to the return field list? Like: `SELECT h.date, e.startdate, e.name [...]`?

Comment: @CodeGodie I have a fiddle [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/371a7/1)

Comment: Just an observation, but it looks like you've given yourself a leap-year bug. Every fourth year has 366 days. When possible, always try to use built-in functions for date & time manipulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the `CONCAT` in this manner:

```
SELECT 
    e.name AS Employee,
    CONCAT(
        CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.startdate)/365), 
        ' (',
        DATE_ADD(e.startdate, INTERVAL FLOOR(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.startdate)/365) YEAR), ' to ',        
        DATE_ADD(e.startdate, INTERVAL CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.startdate)/365) YEAR),
        ')'
        ) as Year,
    COUNT(h.date) AS Holidays_Taken,
    SUM(h.hours) AS Hours
FROM employees AS e
LEFT JOIN holidays_taken AS h ON e.id = h.empid
WHERE e.id = 1
GROUP BY Year
```

**DEMO: [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/371a7/15)**

Comment: [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9f2a/4) In the employee table holidays(hours) = 250 how do a sum holidays - hours I have tried on the fiddle demo thanks for your help

Comment: What about leap years 2016 the next one  with 366 days in it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've got your goal, but here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/371a7/14

```
SELECT 
    e.name AS Employee,
    @year := CEIL(DATEDIFF(h.date, e.startdate)/365) AS Year,
    CONCAT(DATE_ADD(e.startdate, INTERVAL @year-1 YEAR),' - ',DATE_ADD(e.startdate, INTERVAL @year YEAR)),
    COUNT(h.date) AS Holidays_Taken,
    SUM(h.hours) AS Hours
FROM employees AS e
LEFT JOIN holidays_taken AS h ON e.id = h.empid
WHERE e.id = 1 
GROUP BY Year
```

Comment: Great answer but what about leap years the next  one is 2016 with 366 days in it?

Comment: Thanks will take a look and try to implement it into your query